# DateTime.ToString() does not work as expected with slash as date-separator

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to convert the date time to "MM/dd/yyyy" and when i am converting to this format the date is getting like "xx-xx-xxxx". I have written code like

```
  var format = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm";
  DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
  var dateString = dt.toString(format); // the value i am getting is 05-28-2014 12:47 but i require the 'dateString' value to be `05/28/2014 12:53`.
```

What is the issue with that.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Your currrent culture's date-separator seems to be `-` that's why you get it. You have to specify `InvariantCulture`:

```
string dateString = dt.toString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

See: [The "/" Custom Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#dateSeparator)

> The "/" custom format specifier represents the date separator, which
>   is used to differentiate years, months, and days. The appropriate
>   localized date separator **is retrieved from the
>   DateTimeFormatInfo.DateSeparator property of the current or specified
>   culture**.

Another way is to escape the `/` with `\`:

```
string dateString = dt.toString(@"MM\/dd\/yyyy HH\:mm");
```

But in my opinion, if you already know the special meaning of `/` as "current culture's date-separator",  it's better(in terms of readability) to use the correct `CultureInfo` (or `InvariantCulture`) instead.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on your current culture date-separator. Try to include InvariantCulture as follows:

```
var dateStringFormat= dt.toString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: How is it different from answer provided by @TimSchmelter?

Answer (score 1):

Another way from @TimSchmelter's answer is to escape special symbols `/` and `:` so they are not treated as day and time separators.

```
var dateString = dt.toString(@"MM\/dd\/yyyy HH\:mm");
```

Answer (score 0):

you will specified the format  while converting date and time i.e.  DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm ss tt")

for more ref.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx

Comment: How is this different to OP's approach?